# Create base class from interface

Tags: c#, class, interface

How do you create an instance of base class from a class that shares the same interface? Below is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
interface IBASE { }

public class BASE : IBASE { }

class TestClass : IBASE { }

void main()
{
    TestClass tc = new TestClass();
    IBASE ib = (IBASE)tc;
    BASE b = (BASE)ib; // error
}
```

What I want to do is have the interface in a different assembly where the user only has access to that assembly and that interface and creates a class with the interface.
I'm trying to use this as a method of extension, I'm trying to roll out my own instead of using MEF or other solutions, but I have a feeling I'm going about this the wrong way.

So what's the solution?
Thanks.

Comment: The term for the thing you are looking for is "[Duck Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)".

Answer (score 1):

That is completely impossible.

You cannot cast an object to a class unless the its runtime type actually inherits that class.

Comment: how about implicit/explicit operator overloading ?

Comment: @Selman22: That won't help; there is no way to convert that object to that class.  (you could return a separate instance of a different class, but that's not what he wants)

Comment: Other than impossible, any suggestions?

Comment: @Glen: No; it's impossible.  What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you need the base class?

Comment: You could write a proxy implementation that forwards to the interface.